# What is the url for Couchbase UI?

Tags: couchbase

I used couchdb before and really liked the UI, because I can create views and test them directly in UI and view documents.

Because, I need to scale, I started using couchbase. But, after installing couchbase, I don't know the url of couch base client side UI.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just use public IP of any of the nodes in the cluster and connect to port 8091, like this http://example.com:8091

Comment: Is there a way to login as non admin user?

Comment: Is there a way to login as non admin user?

Comment: There is no non-admin login in Couchbase 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's served via 8091. But I would read through this section of the docs: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-bestpractice-cloud-ip.html; when it comes to IP's.

//Daniel

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB's GUI is available at http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils